# "Can't find PInvoke DLL 'sqlceme35.dll"

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, compact-framework, sql-server-ce

I recently installed the new Windows Mobile 6.5.3 SDK upgrading my old Windows Mobile 6 project.

I'm getting an error: "Can't find PInvoke DLL 'sqlceme35.dll" when I try to invoke SQL libraries (this is managed code obviously).

Any ideas how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ok it turns out I had to re-install Visual Studio 2008 AND the SqlCe files to get this issue resolved...

Comment: I had to do same, Still Don't Like It.

Answer (score 4):

Have you installed the SQL Server CE to it?

Never used the Mobile SDK,  so I'm taking a stab in the dark here, but this blog lists the primary reasons you would get that error, and the solution for them: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlservercompact/archive/2007/10/26/can-t-find-p-invoke-dll-sqlcemenn-dll.aspx

Google seems to indicate that a lot of people's problems were with the cab files or not having installed server CE.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if that would work (because it might need other files as well to run properly which I'm not aware of), but I would try to include that DLL in my project so it gets copied to the device along with the other files.